# How to pass event to lower level in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3.js map with polygons and a text over thoose polygons. And I have an event .on which changes the color of the polygon on mouseover event. But when the mouse is over the text(the text is over the polygon) the event did not fires. 
How to fix it?
Thanks

```
 chart.selectAll("path")
    .data(data.features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .style("fill", function(data) {
        return regions[data.properties.FID]
    })
    .style("stroke", "#fff")
    .on("mouseover", function(e) {
        d3.select(this).style("fill", "#63CBF8");
    })
chart.selectAll("text")
    .data(data.points)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "labs")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + projection(d.geometry.coordinates) + ")";
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d, i) {
        return (d.properties.name).toString();
    });
```

Comment: In the text selection, add this: `.attr("pointer-events", "none")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By far the easiest way to do this, is by preventing the text from registering any clicks or mouse behaviour at all. This can be controlled via the [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events). You could do it via CSS or JavaScript. Here are the two approaches below:

**css**

```
.labs {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

**javascript**

```
chart.selectAll("text")
    .data(data.points)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "labs")
    .attr("pointer-events", "none");
```

Comment: It wasn't me, but you have an error in your JS: it needs to be `pointer-events`, not `point-events`! And you could further clarify, that these are two distinct approaches actually.

Comment: @altocumulus thanks, I've taken that on board and edited.